# Error with function C, incompatible type and segmentation fault core dump

Tags: c, codeblocks

Hey so I'm trying to make a program that takes a phrase and puts a word in the middle of it, heres the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5

void Inserir(float A[N], int x, float palavra) {
    int i;
    for (i=N;i>x;i--){
        A[i]=A[i-1];
    }
    A[x]=palavra;
    for (i=0;i<=N;i++){
        printf("A[i] ");
    }
}

void main () {
    int i, x;
    float frase[N];
    float palavra;
    printf("frase? ");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("palavra %d: ",i); scanf("%f",&frase[i]);
    }
    printf("lugar da palavra nova? ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("palava nova? "); scanf("%f",&palavra);
    Inserir(frase[N],x, palavra);
}
```

but on `Inserir(frase[N])` it gives error:incompatible type for argument 1 of "Inserir";
But it's requires to be float, and it is float, whats wrong? I've changed the types around and when it doesnt give this error and build, its crashes in the middle with "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Please properly format your code when you ask questions.

Comment: `Inserir(frase[N],` --> `Inserir(frase,`. Also `i=N` --> `i=N-1`, `i<=N` --> `i<N`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Nice catch. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't think it's a typo. OP mentioned the line explicitly, I think there's a misunderstanding about how to pass an array.

Answer (score 3):

You are goining out of bounds. Your array `A` has lenght of `N`, so your elements have indices 0, 1 ... N-1. Apart from this, to print a `float`number you have to adept call of `print`.

```
void Inserir(float A[N], int x, float palavra) {
    int i;
    for (i=N-1;i>x;i--){ // <- N-1
        A[i]=A[i-1];
    }
    A[x]=palavra;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++){ // <- i<N
        printf( "%f", A[i] );
    }
}
```

`frase[N]` means the Nth element in the array, not the array itself. Apart from this index `N` is out of bounds. Adept this in your `main`:

```
int main() {
   ...
   Inserir(frase,x, palavra);
   ...
}
```